# Python Selenium: Microsoftonline login not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to login to Office 365 Outlook using Python Selenium, that redirects for 2 factor Auth.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

email_ID = "YourEmail@Gmail.com"
Password = "Password"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\pythonLibs\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get("https://outlook.office365.com/mail/inbox")

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until
    (
        # EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
        EC.url_contains("login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize")
    )
finally:
    print("2nd Login Page Reached.")
    print(driver.current_url)

    # Login
    driver.find_element_by_id("i0116").send_keys(email_ID)
    # driver.find_element_by_id("i0118").send_keys(Password) #passwordBrowserPrefill
    print("Login Entered")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]').submit()
```

On the the 1st page redirect (2nd Page) after entering email and submitting, it hits me with a page of

> Sign in
>
> Sorry, but we’re having trouble with signing you in.
>
> AADSTS90100: login parameter is empty or not valid.

If I comment out the submit, and click Next manually after email has been entered it works as normal.

I have previously tried adding an implicit wait before submitting, but to no avail

I look forward to your suggestions.

Comment: the `id` may change, try using the `name` attribute  `name="loginfmt"`

Comment: Add a sleep before clicking on Next: `time.sleep(1)`; then click on Next, not "submit":  `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]').click()`

Comment: @PedroLobito, "loginfmt" is the name for id "i0116" for entering email, and that already works fine. I'm trying to click the next button after entering that information.

Comment: @svetlannnka Yep that was it, the .click() Could have sworn I tried that before but it works now, cheers mate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]').click()
```

Instead of:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]').submit()
```

Because it seems that you're submitting the login form before all the required values are entered.